# Image to Byte array in J2ME

Tags: java-me

How  to convert image to byte array in J2ME ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the original (probably compressed) image back.  But you can use [Image.getRGB()][1] to retrieve the RGB data; this can then be stored somewhere, and the image reconstructed later.  This will take up more space than the original .png (or whatever format it was); you'll need to compress it yourself if that is unacceptable.

[1]: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getRGB(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: :D:D:D Brilliant! You've downrated my answer first, and then copied second part of it as your proposal, and now you're waiting for UP-votes.

Comment: ??  Your link points to a method using Image.getPixel() which isn't available in J2ME.

Comment: OK, now read the sentence again ...and again if it still didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function getRGB, it will return the byte array!

getRGB(rgbs, 0, image.getWidth() , 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

Answer (score -1):

- Did you try toString? *(don't know if that works, just guessing)*
- You can call getRGB in [loop](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/java_beginners/372746/372746/how-to-convert-a-image-to-string-and-then-back/) to get all the pixel values.

Comment: Written following code for getting byte [] out of image ..

byte[] capturedImageData = imageOnScreen.toString().getBytes();

Is it right ?